# How to increase by 1 all keys in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the simplest solution to increase by 1 all keys in an array?

**BEFORE:**

```
$arr[0] = 'a';
$arr[1] = 'b';
$arr[2] = 'c';
```

**AFTER:**

```
$arr[1] = 'a';
$arr[2] = 'b';
$arr[3] = 'c';
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Brad Just for fun :p

Comment: Good question! Shame to all the people who closed this! There are a lot of situations for this. Shifting/offset is a very common action.

Comment: Actually I need an answer for this question now, I'd like not only to increase both also to decrease :)

Comment: @Telvin Nguyen, maybe like this? :-)

`<!-- language: lang-php -->
$new_array = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   $new_array[$key-1] = $value;
}
`$arr = $new_array;`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use

```
$start_zero = array_values($array); /* Re-Indexing Array To Start From Zero */
```

And if you want to start it from index 1 use

```
$start_one = array_combine(range(1, count($array)), array_values($array));
```

Comment: Thanks. That might work. I was looking for "one line" solution. :-)

Comment: Note this will *re-index* they array. Keep this in mind if your indexes are not sequential as technically that could alter the index by more or less than 1.

Comment: if i have array with keys from 0 to 4 and replace range(1, to range(5. it doesnt work neither increasing array, any suggestions ?

Comment: Thanks Mandara & Mr. Alien. I've figured it out. If you want to add to array follow this steps :
     $countPrevArray = count($arrayPrev);
     $arrayToAdd = array_combine(range($countPrevArray, count($addArray)+$countPrevArray-1), array_values($addArray));
     $arrayPrev = $arrayPrev + $arrayToAdd;

Comment: Why is `array_values()` needed in the second line?

Comment: Be aware that if the array is empty, it gives this error `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the actual question.  This reindexes the array starting by one.  OP asked how to increase by 1 all keys in the array.  If there are missing keys, this code will not work as the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 34):

Well, there's one very simple way to do it:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
array_unshift($arr, null);
unset($arr[0]);
print_r($arr);
/* 
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
)
*/
```

Will work only for simple *dense* arrays, of course.

And this is most untrivial (yet both a one-liner AND working for both dense and sparse arrays) way:

```
$arr = array_flip(array_map(function($el){ return $el + 1; }, array_flip($arr)));
```

Comment: +1 This is the most straightforward if you do not wish to reset the indexes.

Comment: ..Works perfectly.. This should be the answer... Thanks!

Comment: ONLY works on arrays with scalar values.  For instance won't work if the value of an element is an array / object.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but you should just be able to loop through:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   $new_array[$key+1] = $value;
}
$arr = $new_array;
```

Comment: @Stan: What do you mean by that? Are you explicitly trying to overcomplicate a trivial solution?

Comment: I just was looking for a "one line" solution.

Comment: +1 from me. I think this is the most complete solution, as it will work both for dense and sparse arrays. Of course, it's not as list-comprehensive as other solutions, but it should be the fastest one AND the most readable. Still, I wonder didn't we just miss another `homework` candidate here. )

Comment: This will bring you into trouble in some situation. If you increase [1] by one, then you will overwrite [2]. In your example it will work as foreach works with a copy of the array, but in oop or referenced programming this will kill you

Comment: @Panique - It shouldn't matter in any case because the original array `$arr` is never touched until it is completely overwritten by `$new_array` in the last line. This is why we use `$new_array` as an intermediate. Is there a specific scenario you'd be worried about?

Comment: @BenD Uh, you are totally right, i just commented under the wrong answer

Comment: This is better than the `array_flip()` based answer because it will work with values that are non-scalar (i.e. array / object / boolean / etc.)

Answer (score 5):

```
$count = count($arr);
for($i=$count; $i>0; $i--){
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i-1];
}
unset($arr[0]);
```

Comment: except that this will result in an array with 4 elements

Comment: Won't work with sparse arrays (like `array('a', 'b', 5 => 'c')`).

Comment: That wasn't a spec in the OP's question. It won't work with associative arrays either. Should we mark everybody's answer wrong since nobody's checks if the key is a string before applying math?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is quite old, but I ran into a similar issue recently and came up with a nice one-liner to solve it for any type of array using an arbitrary integer as the starting key:

```
$array = array_combine(array_keys(array_fill($starting_index, count($array), 0)), array_values($array));
```

$starting_index is whatever value you want for the initial integer key, e.g. 3.

This can even be used with arrays holding complex objects, unlike the solution using array_flip and does not limit you to starting the index at 0 or 1 like some of the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a one liner but it is a different way of doing it

```
$result = array_reduce(array_keys($arr),function($carry,$key) use($arr){
     $carry[$key+1] = $arr[$key]; 
     return $carry;
},[]);
```