# PHP re-structure array from two-dimensional array to array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to know the [php](/questions/tagged/php) way of converting two dimensional array structure to the array of arrays. See the more specific example below:

I have data structure like this:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = "aaaa.png";
$_FILES["file"]["type"] = "image/png"; 
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = "/tmp/phpQklCB7"; 
$_FILES["file"]["error"] = "0"; 
$_FILES["file"]["size"] = "37507";
```

And I need it to be restructured to this data structure:

```
Array ( 
    [name] => Array ( [0] => aaaa.png ) 
    [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png ) 
    [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpIERHxT ) 
    [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
    [size] => Array ( [0] => 37507 ) 
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reindex array by increasing and decreasing all of top indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393644/reindex-array-by-increasing-and-decreasing-all-of-top-indexes)

Comment: updated subject, tags, and description to use more professional language

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
<?php
$_FILES["file"]["name"]     = "aaaa.png";
$_FILES["file"]["type"]     = "image/png"; 
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = "/tmp/phpQklCB7"; 
$_FILES["file"]["error"]    = "0"; 
$_FILES["file"]["size"]     = "37507";  

foreach( $_FILES[ 'file' ] as $key => $value )
{
  $new_array[ $key ] = array( $value );
}

var_dump( $new_array );
```

Output

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "aaaa.png"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpQklCB7"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "37507"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why output not same as `Array ( 
    [name] => Array ( [0] => aaaa.png ) 
    [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png ) 
    [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpIERHxT ) 
    [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
    [size] => Array ( [0] => 37507 ) 
)` ?

Comment: The output is the same as you requesting in your question.

Comment: this is my array `[name] => Array ( [0] => aaaa.png )` and this is your `array ["name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "aaaa.png"
  }` it's not same.

Comment: I'm sorry you have lost me, they are the same thing.  Are you trying to remove the speech marks? this is the code working as you wanted - https://eval.in/678573

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
foreach($_FILES[ 'file' ] as $k=> $v )
{
   $arr[ $k ] = array( $v );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one:

```
$arr = array(
   'name' => array(
       0 => 'aaa.png'
   ),
   'type' => array(
       0 => 'image/png'
   ),
   'tmp_name' => array(
       0 => '/tmp/phpIERHxT'
   ),
   'error' => array(
       0 => 0
   ),
   'size' => array(
       0 => 37507
   )
);
```